# is it possible to use list data structure in cuda kernel function?

Tags: list, cuda

I want to use List data structure in Cuda kernel function, like this:

```
    __global__ void kernel(List<int>* list,...)
    {
       int id = threadIdx.x;
       list->add(id);

    }
```

Is it possible? if so, please tell me how. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not possible in general to use routines that are defined in the C++ STL.  These routines and their associated libraries depend on compiled x86 code and are not usable on the GPU.

Comment: do you know how to implement the traverseIterative function in this post: [link](http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/thinking-parallel-part-ii-tree-traversal-gpu/). It has a `list.add(queryObjectIdx, bvh.getObjectIdx(childL));` call in a device function, I don't know how to do that.